# Clipping rasters to mask layer QGIS 2.18, 3.4, 3.6 not working

Tags: raster, polygon, clip

Having a problem clipping a singleband GEOTIFF of Canadian land uses to a vector Quebec provincial boundary.  When I do Raster -> Extraction -> Clip by mask layer, the program processes endlessly.  I never get an error message; it just doesn't stop. Out of curiosity, I let the process run for more than 24 hours in QGIS 3.4 just to see what would happen.  Never got a result.  I've also tried in QGIS 2.18 and 3.6. No luck. I assembled the raster coverage from five separate files that were each in their own UTM zone. I merged and reprojected to CRS 4269 (NAD 83). The resulting raster is quite large (~15 gigs), but I'm not sure that's the problem.  I made sure the vector is in the same CRS, so I don't believe that's the problem either.  I thought at first it might be some problem with my files, but I brought them to school and was able to clip the raster in ArcMAP.  It took a while to process -- maybe 20 minutes or so -- but that worked.  I've found a few mentions of similar-but not exactly the same-problems in other forums online.  Is this a known issue with QGIS or user error?  Is there a good work-around besides switching to ARC?

[image: raster information]

[image: results from running raster information tool]

[image: vector information screenshot]

[image: command parameters I selected]

[image: processing message]

New: [image: jpeg screenshot of osgeo shell command]

Comment: This is an interesting situation!  I'm surprised that Arc worked - in my experience it tends to be more "fragile" than QGIS.  I don't have a solution, but here are three considerations, all data-based: 1) You were correct when you did your analysis with all data in the same CRS.  However, I would have reprojected the individual rasters to 4269 *before* I merged them.  2) Make sure that all of the input rasters have the same characteristics: # bands, pixel depth, pixel type, etc.  3) The vector layer may be defective; check its geometry (Check Geometries tool) and repair if necessary.

Comment: Please, @Jaime DeWeese, include the *Raster Information* tool output and the *GDAL/OGR console call* of the *Clip Raster by Mask Layer* tool.

Comment: @StuSmith Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the vector layer and it didn't have any geometry errors. I'm going to work on reassembling the merged raster as you suggested and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thanks, I've edited the post to include the screenshots you suggested.

Comment: @JamieDeWeese, try with a folder without the "space" and "É" characters. Try it from the OSGeo4W shell: navigate to the folder and use the command `gdalwarp -of GTiff -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata 255 -ot Byte -cutline Qebec_Nad83_4269.shp -crop_to_cutline Merged_land_use_quebec.tif Cutted.tif`. QGIS takes a lot of time (maybe creating a temporary file is the issue, try saving the output to disk intead), but GDAL needs 15 minutes to create a 50000P x 35000L cutted file, of 5GB without compression (not BIGTIFF creation option required). If it works, feel free to write the correct answer.

Comment: @gabrieldeluca , tried again ... moved everything to a desktop folder and used the OSGeo4W shell to run the the command.  No luck.  I'm posting another photo that shows the command I used and the message I got.  It just said it was processing but never created an output.

Comment: @JamieDeWeese, can you cut the original rasters (before merging) with the same polygon?

Comment: Hey, @gabrieldeluca. That did the trick.  I managed to clip the original rasters before merge.   I don't know why, but it worked.